# How do I set spacing between 2 elements in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Let say I have two elements `<img>` and `<p>` as

```
<img style="background-color:#ffffff;width:250px;height:auto;float:left" src="http://somesite/p3.png" />
<p>
    alibabaanakjalanan.</p>
```

Currently, the paragraph content is shown exactly nex to the image. How can I set some spacing between the elements ?

Comment: Do Study the margin in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are floating the image you all you have to do is give it some `margin-right`, I would advise moving away from adding the styles inline by maybe giving the image a class something like this although my classname is very weak:

**CSS**

```
.img {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:250px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://somesite/p3.png" class="img" />
<p class="para">alibabaanakjalanan.</p>
```

**In action** http://jsfiddle.net/PqWAh/1/

This is best practice for seperating styles from markup

Answer (score 0):

Add margin for `img`.

```
margin-right:20px;
```

So code would be

```
<img style="background-color:#ffffff;width:250px;height:auto;float:left;margin-right:20px;"
```

Comment: but i would recommend to created css file rather using inline css./